New to blender, looking for tips on topology and UV map
Helloo, I'm new to Blender and would like to know if what I've done with the topology and UV map of my model (a low poly cow) is correct or if it can be improved (and if so, how).
I'll take any (kind) tips and good practices you have before texturing it !! :)





UV souds good, topology (in a strict sense) is lacking. (Sometimes this is not a problem, depending on your goals, but) all faces should have 4 sides. I see you have triangles and some polygons with more than 4 vertices. If your goal is to keep low poly until the end, this will probably not be a problem at all. If you want to use subdivision surface, it will probably create bad results because of the topology

@DanielMöller Thank you for your quick response! I'll try to make more (if not all) faces into quads. Is there a way to do this quickly, or do I have to go over each one?

hello, what is the final purpose of your object and how do you plan to texture it?

@moonboots hi ! It doesn't really have a purpose, just seeing what I can do with blender. I already tried to print it in 3D for example, but I would like to maybe make low poly renders with it so add an armature and texturing it with my tablet by drawing on the UV map

if it's a low poly object you don't need quads, ngons are ok, as for the texture, you could paint its texture in Texture Paint mode in the 3D view, in that case no need for seams, you could simply choose the Smart UV Project unwrap mode
